# How to delete a dictionary from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Let's say I have this:

```
d_list = [ {'id':1, 'Name': 'Hannah', weight:150}, {'id':2, 'Name':'Andrew', weight:200}, {'id':3, 'Name':'Joe', weight:180}, {'id':3, 'Name':'Joe', weight:180}]
```

How can I possibly remove say the dictionary with id 3? (so I the dictionary list will contain id 1, 2 and 4) or people that weight over 180 (so I won't have id 2 anymore)

I've tried everything from easy things like

```
for d in d_list:
    if d['weight'] > 180:
        d_list.pop(d)
```

To other things I found on google but to no avail. I'm sorry if that's been posted before or if it seems super easy but I've been looking for hours for something to help me and nothing did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as it is not a good idea to delete from a list you are iterating over i suggest the following list comprehension:

```
d_list = [item for item in d_list if item['weight'] <= 180]
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for the suggestion, I've actually tried that code in my main program and it did nothing. Not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: did you assign the list comprehension to `d_list`? or did you use it inside a function?

Comment: and by the way: your code is not correct python (unless you assiged `weight` to someting): you need to use `'weight'` as a string.

Comment: Oh yea, my bad, I wrote that example purely random, truth is my program is somewhat more complex.
I have a function that takes the parameters the dictionary list and the value I want to compare other key's values with so I know what to delete

Also, fun thing, if I use .remove it will always skip 1 element in between, say I want to remove first 8 dictionaries, 2, 4, 6 and 8 won't get removed.

Comment: '2, 4, 6 and 8 won't get removed': that's what happens if you modify a list as you are iterating over it...

Comment: Ok, I tried using your code outside a separate function and it works now, thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
index = next(index for index, dictionary in enumerate(d_list)
             if dictionary['id'] == 3)

delete d_list[index]
```

Answer (score 1):

pop() for arrays takes an integer as an argument, not an object. Use

```
d_list.remove(d)
```

instead.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html